# Finding elements of a set that is itself a group under addition.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let p and q be distinct primes.

Suppose that H is a proper subset of the integers and H is a group under addition that contains exactly three elements of the set  $\big\{p,p+q,pq,p^{q},q^{p}\big\} .$

Determine which of the following are the three elements in H.

I'm looking for a hint to do this question. A vital clue and the reasoning behind would be really helpful!

Comment: Note that if p is in the group, p+p+p...+p (q times) is also in the group (thus p*q), and that p^q is also in the group since you can generate it by adding p to itself a sufficient number of times.

Comment: @barrycarter When you chose p, is there a reason? Why not use q are a generator?

Comment: @barrycarter Does this requires knowledge of subset and generator? My practice question might be well ahead of the chapter on subset and generators

Comment: I was just giving a hint. If you choose q as a generator, you can't have p or p+q, and you can't have p^q since p^q is not a multiple of q, and all elements in the group generated by q must be multiples of q.

Comment: @barrycarter Just to be sure that I understood correctly the question.
In rephrasing the question, do I ask "For what 3 elements in the set {...} such that H is a group under addition?"
Then, I proceed to assume either p or q is a generator and what elements it generates s.t H forms a group.

Comment: Actually, I think any three elements in the set will generate a group (as will any 3 integers). You need to find a group that contains 3 of the elements of the set but does NOT contain the other 2. In other words, *exactly* 3 are in the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check each element to see what it generates and what it can't generate. If you end up with too many elements then you're out of luck for that generator, and if you end up with too few then you need to add another generator from the set. Try this until you get something with exactly 3 elements.

Comment: So the technique is via 'elimination'?

Comment: More like trial and error, I'd say.

Comment: I'm getting there although I'm not comfortable using the idea of 'generator' before that chapter comes along.
One thing bugs me still: If p in in the set, is there a theorem from which(is it Euclid algorithm?) I can ascertain that qp for some q multiple is in the set? @barrycarter

Comment: If p is in the group, *all* multiples of p must also be in the group, and p*q is certainly a multiple of p.

Comment: A group is closed under its operation (in this case addition) and inverses (these two together here give subtraction), so if $p$ is in the group then so are all multiples of it (and thus exponents). This is essentially what it means to look at the subgroup generated by $p$.

Answer (score 1):

First, observe that the set $$S=\{p,p+q,p q,p^q,q^p\}$$ has exactly 5 members because $p,q$ are distinct primes. Second,observe $1\not \in H,$ else $H=Z$ and then $H$ contains all 5 members of $S.$ Third, observe that $p+q$ is co-prime to each of the other 4 members of $S.$ Therefore $p+q\not \in H.$ Proof:  If $p+q\in H,$ let $x\in H$ with $x\in S$ and $x\ne p+q.$ Then $A(p+q)$ and $B x$ belong to $H$ for all integers $A,B$, and there exist integers $A,B$ with $A(p+q)+B x=1$ (because $p+q$ and $x$ are co-prime), implying $1\in H.$ Fourth,we have $p\in H.$ Proof.If $p\not \in H$ then $S\cap H=\{p q,p^q,q^p\}.$ But $p^q$ and $q^p$ are co-prime so there are integers $A,B$ with $1=A p^q+B q^p\in H.$ Fifth,since $p\in H,$ every multiple of $p$ is in $H,$ so $p q$ and $p^q$ are in $H.$ And $q^p\not \in H.$ We conclude that $$H\cap S=\{p,p q ,p^q\}.$$ We also conclude that $H=Z p=\{p a :a\in Z\}$ because  (i) $ p\in H\implies Z p\subset H,$ and (ii) if $n\in Z\backslash Z p$  there are integers $A,B$ with $A n+B p=1,$ so $n\not \in H$.

Comment: I think this can be shortened by noting near the beginning that since $S$ has 5 members, no two members of $S\cap H$ can be co-prime, otherwise $H=Z\supset S$.

Comment: What happens if you pose the same Q but with no restrictions on p,q except  for being integers?